# Why is switching between two components so ridiculously slow on Android?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm building a small puzzle app similar to a crossword using Expo/React Native/Typescript.

And here's a condensed version of the PuzzleMain component:

```
const PuzzleMain: React.FC<PuzzleMainProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
    let puzzle: AcrosticPuzzleData = parseAcrosticPuzzle(PUZZLE_TEXT);

    const grid = <PuzzleGrid puzzle={puzzle} />;
    const clueView = <PuzzleCluesView puzzle={puzzle} />;

    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

    return <View style={styles.container}>
        {index == 0 ? grid : clueView}
        <View style={styles.keyboardContainer}>
            <Button onPress={() => setIndex(index == 1 ? 0 : 1)} title={"See " + routes[index == 0 ? "Grid" : "Clues"].key} />
            <Keyboard />
        </View>
    </View>;
}
```

To summarize, there are a "grid" component and "clues" components, and a button is used to switch between them.

Tapping this button takes, without exaggeration, about 3 full seconds to make the change on the Pixel 5 I'm using to test. What am I doing wrong here? Using Expo to open this on web, it happen instantly, so it's possible it's specific to Android?

Things I've tried:

1. Memoizing the `PuzzleGrid` and `PuzzleCluesView` components (`const PuzzleGrid: React.FC<Props> = memo(({ puzzle }) ...`. This made basically no difference. I checked and nothing prints in a custom puzzle comparator I made for the memo function, so I don't think it's re-rendering.
2. Switching to using TabView to swipe between components instead - this worked! But I'd really prefer to have both honestly, and the button was equally slow when I incorporated it into the TabView implementation.
3. Using `npx expo start --no-dev` and just building an apk and installing - this made it faster, but still probably a full second or two, which is way too slow.

Comment: I hope that by viewing the discussion and going over the issues, your question will be answered : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11167

Comment: I'm on 0.73.1 so unfortunately I don't think that's likely to apply to me. I looked over the thread and the only thing that maybe seemed relevant is dbankier mentioning that `setOptions` is slow, which could explain the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: Okay, I did what I should have done a while ago and added a button outside of the React Navigation header and it still takes equally long, which surprised me. Seems like it's a rendering time issue then? Which would explain why TabView solved the issue (presumably it keeps both of them rendered) but weird to me that Memo didn't solve the issue (and weird to me that changing the index on a TabView presumably sets off the same re-render when swiping doesn't?)

Comment: `memo()` and `useMemo()` do nothing to improve the initial render of your component, they only help with subsequent renders. I suspect that your components have some slow code, you should log how much javascript takes to execute. There might also he a problem if you have a huge number of jsx elements. PC CPU is much faster than mobile CPU, so that is likely why you don't notice any problem in the browser.

Comment: Try to wrap `<PuzzleGrid />` with `useMemo(() => <PuzzleGrid />, [])` and similar for `<PuzzleCluesView />`

Comment: @AlokPrakash That is not going to change anything

Comment: If puzzle type is object then you must need to memoize it or create it inside the child component.

Answer (score 2):

as I can see you are doing conditional rendering, so every time the condition changes the whole component is created as new. This approach makes the render slow based on how heavy your component is.

Why does not memo work?
Memo is an optimisation technique and it does not guarantee performance enhancement.

Now, to enhance the load speed

1. Optimize the `PuzzleGrid` and `PuzzleCluesView` internally, like each sub-component that can receive duplicate props is covered in memo and heavy items are loaded with async, use loader.
2. Using [InteractionManager](https://reactnative.dev/docs/interactionmanager) to improve loading speed, and help with showing loader without freezing UI.
3. Rather than unmounting the components, overlap them and use visibility, as visibility will not unmount the component, I recommend Interaction manager with this, as heavy components rendering in parallel can slow down the UI.

Instead of just
`{index == 0 ? grid : clueView}` you can try something like

```
  <View>
    {grid}
    <View
      style={{
        // Add height and other required props to make it visible
        position: 'absolute',
        display: index == 0 ? 'none' : 'flex',
      }}>
      {clueView}
    </View>
  </View>
```

Checked your shared code and updated PuzzleMain.tsx

```
const PuzzleMain: React.FC<PuzzleMainProps> = ({ puzzle }) => {
  ...
  const [showClues, setShowClues] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {grid}
        <View
          style={{
            display: showClues ? "flex" : "none",
            position: "absolute",
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
          }}
        >
          {clueView}
        </View>
      </View>
      <Button
        onPress={() => setShowClues(!showClues)}
        title={`See ${showClues ? "Cues" : "Grid"}`}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Adding screen recording, it's snappy now!

[image]

Comment: I'm following this advice as best I can, but unfortunately it's still taking ages to render (using TabView did fix the "switching" problem, but I still need to update sub-component state like "highlightedSquare", and that takes just as long as it re-renders every component). I even made the arePropsEqual function `return true` for every single child component, and react devTools still clocks those child components as taking the bulk of the render time. I'm worried I'm missing something silly (found StrictMode while googling - does Expo use that by default or something?)

Comment: Here's the repo if you're willing to look: https://github.com/JamesSto/acrostic

Comment: @James Thank you for sharing the code, I have updated the answer with working code and sample output, please have a look 

Comment: I noticed `const grid =` is defined inside `PuzzleMain`, declaring functions or variables like this causes a new instance for every re-render(when the state changes). This slows down the UI. I would recommend to use it in return and pass props to it directly.

Comment: As mentioned, you are facing lag with click, it's because of nested loops, as everything is building again on click of the Square.

You have to find a way only to update one single element or only update one row/column in which an item is clicked to increase speed.

Alternatively, you can use setNativeProps `https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation`

Comment: I have made a Snack to help you understand how you can handle clicking without re-rendering the whole Grid system, please mind that this is for reference to help you understand as a reference and is not a final solution. Please check here https://snack.expo.dev/@rajrohityadav/grid-with-select